# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay not working inside viewDidLoad method

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, viewdidload

I have a tabbar application, the problem is that i need to call a method after a delay of viewDidLoad of the first view but it didn't work (the method is not called)
i added the following sample

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(foo) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

}

-(void)foo
{
    NSLog(@"foo!");
}
```

the strange thing is that this work with all other tabs view but for some reason it didn't work with the first tab (UITableViewController)
any idea??

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with "performSelector"? Did you set a breakpoint (or NSLog) into viewDidLoad? Are you sure viewDidLoad is called? Aren't you reimplementing loadView?

Comment: Does it work in the other method?

Comment: @JohnSmith yea a'm sure it didn't goes into the method, also i have used timer to call the method and it didn't work also. I don't know why it is not working only in this case

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSelector:@selector(foo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
        });

}
```